# Getting failure name as 'Unknown' in Microsoft store app health analytics report

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, crash-reports, windows-store

We are getting 'Unknown' as the reason of failure in Microsoft Store app health analytics report for our **UWP (Universal Windows Platform) App**.

This report is generated from the data collected from the machines of the users who are using our app by downloading it from the Microsoft Store. Crash reason 'Unknown' is the major crash reason, highest among all the crashes faced by the users. we are investigating the reason for this crash, for all other crashes we got the error clearly, but for this we are getting the error name as 'Unknown', which is a generic message and is hard to find the root cause.

Comment: You could try to use [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) to collect logs for your app. It could provide more information about the detailed error messages.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. We are able to collect the logs using AppCenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Roy Li - MSFT, using [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) to collect logs for app gave me more information about the errors.